# Avoiding duplicate row selection in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jide

I need to avoid duplicate row selection in JTable. If previously selected row is selected again, I don't want to fire mouseevent or need some API which can tell me if it is a duplicate row selection. I can maintain indexes for previously selected rows, but want to avoid it , if possible

I am using JIDE table APIs in my functionality, so if there is any JIDE related method which can indicate such scenario.

- Thanks

Comment: Is adding a listener to the selection model not sufficient ? Why would you want to bother with the mouse events ?

Comment: Simply keep track of the rows already selected in a List<Integer>, and check to see if the row was already selected in the first part of your JTable selection listener.